# Bitcoincore wallet 0.20.0

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, wallet, windows, asicboost

Because on windows it is so difficult to load the blockchain into the BitcoinCore wallet. Arrives in 2016 the loading rate increases days. In ubuntu18.04 it is so fast and does not slow down after 2016. When it slows down and checks on windows with bitcoind.exe after 2016 and it finds four errors in the blockchain; how should I proceed?

Comment: It doesn't depend on the node version but from the network status. You couldn't have for all the time the same download velocity. Sometimes yes, sometimes no. Also, you should considerer that the bitcoin core data are big and not all people have the complete copy on their pc, so it mean that only a few nodes on the network has all data available to share. I downloaded the bitcoin network in two different places in the same day and I had some big differences on the timing

Answer (score 0):

It's normal, because the number of transactions are bigger. The blockchain size is very big one, and it depends in your internet speed, it can take even 4 weeks to download the entire blockchain

Comment: My network traffic on debug console is so fast in ubuntu, then one day I charge blockchain, but in windows it is very slow; it will take almost 1 year. Is this normal on windows?

Comment: I addnode almost 20 node on windows debug console but my network traffic isn't continous. Appears and disappears and fades away the registered nodes (20 addnode)

Comment: It will not take one year, even the remaining time will change, sometimes to one year, then to 4 days, then to 4 week, but will take a good period even with a good traffic

Comment: @MinerBr99 It happened to me too when i donwloaded it, it wasn't continous